# Discord.NET SlashCommand RespondAsync hide inputted command and its passed arguments

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

My question is how to hide a message when doing RespondAsync() the user command and its arguments, however if I don't use RespondAsync() it will say application is not responded etc. So, I want to either hide the message or change it because it sends inputted arguments which I don't want to share.

[image: Discord Message Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather here, you want a command which does not display a response that everyone in the same channel can see.

If you only want the user executing the command to see the response, send the response using

```cs
slashCommand.RespondAsync(text, ephemeral: true)
```